# Is there a short way to switch between 'any' and 'all' in condition in function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements, any

I have a function where I check several list of parameters:

```
def check_function(some_input_parameters):
  #do_smth
  ...

  if all(bet_res[i] for i in res_number_list):
     good_row_list.append(row_dict)
  else:
     bad_row_list.append(row_dict)
  #do_smth
  ...
```

In some cases I need "all" and sometimes I need "any".
Is there a nice short way to change all/any by some input param?
I can do smth like this, but I don't like it:

```
if any_all_flag = 'all':
        if all(bet_res[i] for i in res_number_list):
            good_row_list.append(row_dict)
        else:
            bad_row_list.append(row_dict)
else:
        if any(bet_res[i] for i in res_number_list):
            good_row_list.append(row_dict)
        else:
            bad_row_list.append(row_dict)
```

Comment: Just pass an argument to the function, like `any_or_all`, which is `any` or `all`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `all` and `any` functions accept iterables, so you don't need to loop over the iterator again, unless you only want to apply the functions on certain number of items. One neat approach here is to use a dictionary like following for preserve the function and their names so that you can access to the respective function by a simple indexing.

```
functions = {'all': all,
             'any': any}

if functions[any_all_flag](bet_res):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: I agree this is a clean method. Out of interest, would this be more or less efficient than using a ternary statement, e.g. `if (all if flag else any)(iterable)...`?

Comment: @jpp dict is 74.2 ns, ternary is 84 ns on my machine. So basically no different.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Just use a functor (a variable that is holding a function):

```
if any_all_flag = 'all':
  my_functor = all
else:
  my_functor = any

if my_functor(bet_res[i] for i in res_number_list):
  good_row_list.append(row_dict)
else:
  bad_row_list.append(row_dict)
```